# Serving CHANGING static django files in production

Tags: python, django, whitenoise

I need to serve a static file that has a changing name. This works fine with DEBUG = True, but immediately breaks with DEBUG = False. I'm currently using Whitenoise to serve files in production, and tried executing `collectstatic` after the filename changes, but that didn't help. Any advice is appreciated

Edit: This is how the filename is changed

```
newname = 'myfile' + str(random.randint(0, 999999)) + '.css'
newpath = os.path.join(current_dir, ('../staticfiles/stuff/css/' + newname))
os.rename(r'{}'.format(filepath), r'{}'.format(newpath))
```

I can't quite give full context for why I need this file's name to change

Comment: How is the name changing and why? Can you show the code that changes the filename?

Comment: Are you changing the filename in your STATIC_ROOT folder or in the source directory? Running collectstatic will only work if the file is in a source directory and not in STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your whitenoise configured correctly?  I mean, except for this static file all other files are working fine. If yes share your static_root and static_url and staticfiles_dirs settings.

Comment: Yes, all other files are working fine. It seems that whitenoise doesn't start serving new files from the static root unless I execute `runserver` again. Is there a way to force whitenoise to serve all files in the directory even as new ones are added?

My settings:
`STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"`